# Как в Golang отобрать все цифры из строки?

Tags: golang

Подскажите: как в го вытащить цифры из строки?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать регулярное выражение:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"

func main() {
    str := "Hello, today is January 11. I am 28 now. Date of birth 11.01.1990."

    fmt.Println("Test string", str)

    re := regexp.MustCompile("[0-9]+")
    fmt.Println(re.FindAllString(str, -1))
}
```

Запустить код можно здесь: https://play.golang.org/p/4FayPuOwBSx

Comment: Можно сократить до `\d+`: https://play.golang.org/p/Cjo_0_Xmpac.